# Why is there so many sidekiq process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I ran htop in my production server to see what was eating my RAM. A lot of sidekiq process is running, is this normal?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Shift-H.  htop shows individual threads as processes by default.  There is only one actual sidekiq process.

Comment: And maybe upgrade?  Your sidekiq version is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have configured it to have 25 workers.

```
By default, one sidekiq process creates 25 threads. 
If that's crushing your machine with I/O, you can adjust it down:

sidekiq -c 10
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

If you are not using JRuby then it's likely these all are seperate processes that consume memory.

Comment: Hi Peterdk, I counted all the sidekiq process and they are more than 25. Am i missing something?

Comment: Hi, Ok, that's weird indeed. I assume then somehow they do not get killed properly when restarting/redeploying. Maybe you can test that. I assume you don't use multiple sites each with sidekiq?